# React Native InjectJavaScript

Tags: react-native

Is there any possibility of retrieving two values from a react-native WebView using injectJavaScript.

My code is as following:

```
 jsCode = "window.postMessage(document.cookie=total_status);";
 jsCode1 = "window.postMessage(document.cookie=totaltimespent);";





  <WebView

    source={{ uri: uri }}
    style={styles.WebView}
    onMessage={this._onMessage}
    onError={this.onError}
    injectedJavaScript={jsCode}
    startInLoadingState={true}
    scalesPageToFit={true}
  />
```

I also want to retrieve the value of jsCode1.

Can somebody help me out in solving my problem?

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

**You should be able to combine both into a single code snippet that would call `postMessage` twice:**

```
jsCode = `
          window.postMessage(document.cookie=total_status);
          window.postMessage(document.cookie=totaltimespent);
          true;
        `;
```

**OR**

`jsCode_combined = jsCode + jsCode1 + 'true;'` 
and `injectedJavaScript = {jsCode_combined}`

Note that the `true` at the end in both cases seems to be required when the return type of the injected JS is not supported / expected, and is there as a safe measure for those cases.

**OR**

You can also use `injectJavascript` on a ref to the webview. You will need to set a ref to the web view like so:

```
<WebView
  ref={r => this.webview = r}
/>
```

How `injectJavascript` is used, is by calling it on the ref of the webview to inject more JS programmatically on the fly.
In this case it could look something like this for example:

```
this.webview.injectJavascript(jsCode1);
```

You could do this in `render`, on an event like a click, or wherever else you want.